# How do i handle the null pointer exception error in the below udf

Tags: scala

I am trying to run the udf `udfTest` on the below df ,but its running into 
null pointer exceptions possibly due to nulls in date1 column. What change is needed in the code below to handle this exception?

```
 +-----------+----------------+----------+
    |info       |date1           | date2    |
    +-----------+----------------+----------+
    |      11111|      2018-04-13|2018-05-20|
    |      11111|                |2018-05-20|
    |      22222|      2018-05-01|2018-05-18|
    |      22222|                |2018-05-20|
    |      33333|      2020-05-03|2018-05-18|
    |      33333|                |2017-04-17|
    |      12931|      2018-05-07|2018-05-07|
    |      12931|      2018-05-03|2018-05-04|
    |      12931|      2018-05-20|2018-05-26|
    |      12931|      2008-05-03|2018-05-20|
    +-----------+----------------+----------+

def get_value(info: String, date1: String, date2: String): String = {
    var str1: String = null
    if (info == "11111" && date1 != null) {
      str1 = date1
    } else if (info == "22222" && date1 != null) {
      str1 = date1
    } else if (info == "33333" && date2 != null) {
      str1 = date2
    } else
      str1 = null
    str1
  }


  val udfTest = udf((id: String, date1: String, date2: String) => {
    get_value(id: String, date1: String, date2: String)
  })
  df.withColumn("date3", udfTest(df("info"),df("date1"), df("date2")))
```

error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:152)
  at get_value(<console>:61)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could consider using Option's to encapsulate nulls. Nulls littered in scala code is generally considered a code smell. Perhaps, something to this effect might help.

```
val getValue: (String, String, String) => Option[String] = { (info, date1, date2) =>
  (info, Option(date1), Option(date2)) match {
    case ("11111", Some(d1), _) => Some(d1)
    case ("22222", Some(d1), _) => Some(d1)
    case ("33333", _, Some(d2)) => Some(d2)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Then you can use it in your UDF as follows,

```
val udfTest = udf(getValue)
df.withColumn("optional", udfTest(df("info"), df("date1"), df("date2"))).show()
```

Note that now instead of a String column you have an Option[String] column in your dataframe.

[Here's](https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html) an interesting guide to the Optional data type in scala, and interesting use cases.

Edit:

Something like this then to address you question about translating the holiday spark sql code

```
private val yyyyMMddFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
private val days = List("Saturday", "Sunday")
private val holidays = List(
  getPreviousDay("2018-05-22"), 
  getPreviousDay("2018-06-01")
)

def isPreviousDayAHoliday(date: String, days: List[String], holidays: List[java.sql.Date]): Boolean = {
  val previousDay = getPreviousDay(date)
  val eeeeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE")
  val dayOfPreviousDay = eeeeFormat.format(previousDay)
  days.contains(dayOfPreviousDay) || holidays.contains(previousDay)
}

def getPreviousDay(date: String): java.sql.Date = {
  new java.sql.Date(yyyyMMddFormat.parse(date).getTime - DAYS.toMillis(1))
}
```

Now you can use this as a guard.

```
(info, Option(date1), Option(date2)) match {
  case ("12391", _, Some(d2)) if isPreviousDayAHoliday(d2, days, holidays) => Some(yyyyMMddFormat.format(getPreviousDay(d2)))
  case _ => None
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is a great answer and is idiomatic scala. I didn't want to diverge from the solution proposed in the answer so I just made the least necessary changes. Anyway I think this should be accepted as the right answer.

Comment: @senjin.hajrulahovic, can you help me out on date comparison as per my previous comment?

Comment: How do i add this code `col("info") === "12931" && col("date2").isNotNull && (!lit(date_format(date_sub($"date2", 1), "EEEE")).isin(days: _*)) && (!lit(date_sub($"date2", 1)).isin(holiday_list: _*)),lit(date_sub($"date2", 1))).otherwise("null")` in the suggested answer ??

Comment: Thanks for the update @rmathews.  Actually if you see my last comment, this is something that i wrote in spark sql. i need to implement the same in your provided code.

Comment: how do it translate this `date_format(to_date($"date", "MM/dd/yyyy"), "EEEE").isin(days: _*)` so that i can use it in `dateMeetsCriterion1`

Comment: I should note that SimpleDateFormat is not threadsafe, and, may not behave well with the example code. I hope this however directionally points you in the right direction. Consider using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: Thanks @rmathews7, one questions though, how to return  None when the condition does not match  in this line `case ("12931", _, Some(date2)) if !dateMeetsHoliday(pd, days, holidays) => Some(getPreviousDate(date2))` , currently its returning `null` for cases where condition does not match

Answer (score 2):

As usual I always advise **not to go with** `udf` functions *when there is alternatives with inbuilt functions*. As `udf` functions require each rows to be serialized and deserialized, its not as efficient as inbuilt functions.

You can achieve your requirement with the use of `when/otherwise`, `isnull` and `not` inbuilt functions as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("date3",
  when(not(isnull(col("date1"))) && col("info") === "11111", col("date1")).otherwise(
  when(not(isnull(col("date1"))) && col("info") === "22222", col("date1")).otherwise(
    when(not(isnull(col("date2"))) && col("info") === "33333", col("date2")).otherwise(lit(null))
  )
  )
)
```

Or just use `when/otherwise` and `isNotNull` functions as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("date3",
  when(col("date1").isNotNull && col("info") === "11111", col("date1")).otherwise(
  when(col("date1").isNotNull && col("info") === "22222", col("date1")).otherwise(
    when(col("date2").isNotNull && col("info") === "33333", col("date2")).otherwise(lit(null))
  )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh... Actually i had already written the working code using inbuilt functions, but I just want to try it out an UDF.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent null pointer exceptions you can compare the String constants to the info variable, not the other way around. You don't really need the str1 variable. The working solution which diverges from you proposal at least is:

```
def get_value(info: String, date1: String, date2: String): String = {
  if ("11111" == info && date1 != null) {
    date1
  } else if ("22222" == info && date1 != null) {
    date1
  } else if ("33333" == info && date2 != null) {
    date2
  } else
    "null"
}
```

Comment: The solution is not working, i have updated the question with the input dataset, please check

Answer (score 0):

using `Option` got it working.

```
   def get_value(info: String, date1: String, date2: String): String = {
    var str1: String = null
  if ("11111" == info && date1 != null) {
    Option(tdate1).getOrElse("null")
  } else if ("22222" == info && date1 != null) {
    Option(tdate1).getOrElse("null")
  } else if ("33333" == info && date2 != null) {
    Option(tdate2).getOrElse("null")
  } else
    Option(str1).getOrElse("null")
}
```

Comment: There is no point in using `Option::getOrElse` since you are already checking for null in the condition.

This is literally the implementation of apply in `scala.Option`: 
    `def apply[A](x: A): Option[A] = if (x == null) None else Some(x)`